# IF statement and limiting numbers displayed (Excel/VBA)

Tags: excel, vba, barcode, barcode-scanner

I am creating a spreadsheet that displays a barcode when a macro is pressed.

Code I have now:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pick Sheet") 'use a worksheet variable
    ws.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "Pick Sheet"

    For a = 5 To 16
        With ws.Cells(a, 3)
            .Value = "*" & .Offset(0, -1).Value & "*"
            .Font.Name = "Free 3 of 9" 'barcode font
            .Font.Size = 32
        End With
    Next
ws.Columns(3).AutoFit
End Sub
```

This creates a new column next to the existing one and changes the font to a readable barcode font while also putting asterisks around the number.

What I want it to also do is to basically only print the barcode if there are numbers in the previous column. Essential "If number exists then perform the barcode code"

On top of this, I only want the barcode to put asterisks around the first 4 digits of the material number. We have material numbers like 1130.201, but I only want the code to include 1130 in the barcode.
[This is what the spreadsheet looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfsdI.png)

[Picture of spreadsheet after code update.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAV03.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm understanding you want:

A) If statement within `With` statement for `IsNumeric()`in `Offset(,-1)`

B) Use `Left(,4)` for your `.Value`

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet, a As Long
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Pick Sheet") 'use a worksheet variable
    ws.Range("C1").EntireColumn.Insert
    ws.Range("C1").Value = "Pick Sheet"

    For a = 5 To 16
        With ws.Cells(a, 3)
            dim checkValue as Variant
            checkValue = .Offset(,-1).Value
            If IsNumeric(checkValue)= True And Len(checkValue)>0 Then
                .Value = "*" & Left(checkValue,4) & "*"
                .Font.Name = "Free 3 of 9" 'barcode font
                .Font.Size = 32
            End if
        End With
    Next
ws.Columns(3).AutoFit
End Sub
```

Edit1:  Adding additional check for `Len()` to `If`-statement and added `checkValue` to limit references to the sheet.

Comment: Close. I am not sure how to add a picture to a comment so I will add it to the original post at the bottom. The Left(,4) worked great. In the picture I will post you'll see there are barcodes for cells that have no numbers in the MATERIAL column. I am trying to make it so no barcode appears if there are no numbers if possible.

Comment: @Ghost7575 See update.  Regarding the images, without knowing how the barcodes are being generated, not a whole lot else to do with it... that may need to be a separate post/question.